# Validating npm package.json

Tags: validation, npm, package.json

I would like to validate my npm `package.json` files as part of my CI/CD pipeline.

Is there an official schema for the file? I found a pretty dated [github project](https://github.com/gorillamania/package.json-validator), but it does not seem official.

Comment: I need that too! Something like `composer validate`